# Memory Allocation and Copying to a new struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

I have a struct like this:

```
typedef struct {
    char* ptr;
    int len;
    int capa;
} String;
```

And I would like to double the memory allocated to an object of this struct. So in the following function I pass a pointer to the struct object; I create another struct object which is double the memory. I copy the information to the new struct and make the pointer point at this struct. Even though there is no error, the memory allocation does not work correctly as output indicates. What might be wrong about the fuction:

```
void DoubleCapacity(String *s){

String k;
k.len=s->len;
k.capa=(s->capa) * 2;
printf("s->capa is %d\n", s->capa );
k.ptr=(char*) malloc(s->capa * 2);

printf("k.capa is %d\n", s->capa*2 );
//printf("%d\n", s->capa);
//printf("%d\n", s->capa *2);
if (k.ptr == NULL) {
    printf("Error occurs when allocating memory\n");
    exit(1);
}


for(int i=0; i < s->len; i++){
    k.ptr[i]=s->ptr[i];

}

s=&k;

}
```

Comment: `k` is local to `DoubleCapacity`

Comment: note that you dont need a new struct, just a new buffer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
s=&k;
```

changes where `s` points to but the change is local to the function. It does not change the contents of the object in the calling function.

1. You don't need to create a new object of type `String`.
2. You need to change `s->ptr` to point to the newly allocated memory.
3. You need to deallocate the old memory that `s->ptr` points to.
4. You need to update the capacity of `s`.

---

```
void DoubleCapacity(String *s) {

    int newCapa = (s->capa) * 2;
    char* ptr = malloc(newCapa);

    if (ptr == NULL) {
        printf("Error occurs when allocating memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Copy the data from old memory to new memory
    memcpy(ptr, s->ptr, len);

    free(s->ptr);
    s->ptr = ptr;
    s->capa = newCapa;
}
```

A better version, by using `realloc`.

```
void DoubleCapacity(String *s) {

    int newCapa = (s->capa) * 2;
    char* ptr = realloc(s->ptr, newCapa);

    if (ptr == NULL) {
        printf("Error occurs when allocating memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    s->ptr = ptr;
    s->capa = newCapa;
}
```

Comment: memcpy rather than loop?

Comment: @pm100, that's definitely better.

Comment: And not `realloc`?

Comment: @DanielH, :) I was trying to minimize the number of changes to the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

For starters the structure should be defined the following way

```
typedef struct 
{
    char* ptr;
    size_t len;
    size_t capa;
} String;
```

The function itself should be declared like

```
int DoubleCapacity(String *s);
```

That is the function should report whether doubling of the capacity was successfull.

This statement

```
s=&k;
```

does not make sense. First of all the poinrer `s` is paased by value and as result the original pointer will not be changed. The function deals with a copy of the original pointer. Secondly you have to free early allocated memory pointed to by the data member `ptr` or you should `realloc` the memory.

The function can be defined the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct 
{
    char *ptr;
    size_t len;
    size_t capa;
} String;

int DoubleCapacity(String *s)
{
    char *tmp = realloc( s->ptr, 2 * s->capa );
    int success = tmp != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        s->ptr = tmp;
        s->capa *= 2;
    }

    return success;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *hello = "Hello Doe";
    String s = { 0 };

    size_t n = strlen( hello );
    s.ptr = malloc( n + 1 );

    if ( s.ptr )
    {
        s.len = n;
        s.capa = n + 1;
        strcpy( s.ptr, hello );
    }

    printf( "s.len = %zu\n", s.len );
    printf( "s.capa = %zu\n", s.capa );
    printf( "s.ptr = \"%s\"\n\n", s.ptr );

    DoubleCapacity( &s );

    printf( "s.len = %zu\n", s.len );
    printf( "s.capa = %zu\n", s.capa );
    printf( "s.ptr = \"%s\"\n\n", s.ptr );

    free( s.ptr );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output

```
s.len = 9
s.capa = 10
s.ptr = "Hello Doe"

s.len = 9
s.capa = 20
s.ptr = "Hello Doe"
```